# Count ++ and -- doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

I'm trying to create a function that when a user clicks on a td element of a table with the class "n" the counter goes one up.

However, upon the click of the td element, it also gets asigned the class "selected". So what I'm trying to do is when a user clicks again on the element with the class "selected" the counter goes -1.

Basically it should work like a toggle that once its cliked, its +1 and clicked again and it goes -1. I have tried this function but it doesn't work.

The code below is my function:

```
$('#plan td')
.bind('click',function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("n"))
        count +=1;
}).bind('click',function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected"))
        count -=1;
    $('.msg span.count').html(count);
});
```

This is resposnible for assigning the class "selected":

```
$('#plan td.n').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass("taken"))
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected") || $(".selected").length < 4) 
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

This is the html part:

```
<div id='plan'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='n' id='_1a'>T</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1b'>F</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1c'>T</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1d'>T</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1e'>F</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1f'>T</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Why not just do `$('#plan .n').click`? 2) You say it's assigned the class `selected` on click but it doesn't look like you're doing that. 3) Don't assign multiple click handlers. In your one handler, just check if it has the class `selected` then increment or decrement based on that.

Comment: And more: 1) where is the HTML part with `msg` class? 2) and `taken`class? 3) and what is the logics about `$(".selected").length < 4`?

Comment: I just posted a bit of my code, the msg class is used to show the count in html and the lenght is < 4 as I only want maximum 4 classes active.

Comment: If the counter is on 1 and you click on another button does the counter then go to 2, or does each button have its own counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change you javascript this way

```
  var count = 0;

  $('#plan  td')
  .bind('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      count -= 1;
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else if ($(".selected").length < 4) {
      count += 1;
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    $('.msg span.count').html(count);
  })
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07tcu5y9/)

Comment: This works actually better then the other responses, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're spreading out your work far too thin. All of this can be handled in one handler.

```
$('#plan .n').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass('selected') || $('.selected').length < 4) {
    $this.toggleClass('selected');
  }
  if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    count -= 1;
  } else {
    count += 1;
  }
  $('.msg span.count').html(count);
});
```

Comment: Omg you are great. Thank you very much, thats excatly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified to:

```
$('.n').click(function(){
  var cnt = $('#cnt').text();
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ){
    cnt ++;
  } else{
    cnt --;
  }
  $('#cnt').text(cnt);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='plan'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='n' id='_1a'>T</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1b'>F</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1c'>T</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1d'>T</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1e'>F</td>
      <td class='n' id='_1f'>T</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<span id="cnt">0</span>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4sck6vse/)